# Bootstrap default padding and margin causing images to stretch outside the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My images are stretching into the padding/margin that bootstrap uses to divide the columns. I want to keep the columns divided but not have the images stretch. I have been able to shrink the image using padding but then the whitespace between the columns is clickable which is not what I want.

```
<div id="cont_divider" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
                <div class="row text_center">
                    <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="inner_cont_1">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p class="stair_image_font_style">Straight<br/>Staircase</p>

                                    <img class="img-responsive staircase_imgs" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/straight.jpg" alt="straight staircase">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
                <div class="row text_center">
                    <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="inner_cont_2">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p class="stair_image_font_style">Single Winder<br/>Staircase</p>

                                    <img class="img-responsive staircase_imgs" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/single_winder.jpg" alt="straight staircase">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
                <div class="row text_center">
                    <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="inner_cont_3">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p class="stair_image_font_style">Double Winder<br/>Staircase</p>

                                    <img class="img-responsive staircase_imgs" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/double_winder.jpg" alt="straight staircase">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
                <div class="row text_center">
                    <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="inner_cont_4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p class="stair_image_font_style">Triple Winder<br/>Staircase</p>

                                    <img class="img-responsive staircase_imgs" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/triple_winder.jpg" alt="straight staircase">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#inner_cont_1{
    background-color: #336699;
}

#inner_cont_2{
    background-color: #cc6633;
}

#inner_cont_3{
    background-color: #ff6633;
}

#inner_cont_4{
    background-color: #ffcc66;
}

.staircase_imgs{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 1.238em 0.3em 1.238em;
}

.stair_image_font_style{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.8em 0.938em;
    margin: 0;
}

.col_divide{
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: try adding the classes `no-padding` and `no-margin`. Or create a class in your `CSS` called something like `no-space` and give it `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have already tried that and it removes the white space between the columns, which I want to keep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using `.row` without a `.col-` class. `.row` has negative left and right margins which will extend the content area out beyond the parent. The padding of a .`col-` class nullifies this affect. Remove `.row`.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

#inner_cont_1 {
  background-color: #336699;
}

#inner_cont_2 {
  background-color: #cc6633;
}

#inner_cont_3 {
  background-color: #ff6633;
}

#inner_cont_4 {
  background-color: #ffcc66;
}

.stair_image_font_style {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0.8em 0.938em;
  margin: 0;
}

.col_divide {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont_divider" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
      <div class="row text_center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
            <div id="inner_cont_1">
                <p class="stair_image_font_style">Straight<br/>Staircase</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/fc0" alt="straight staircase">
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
      <div class="row text_center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
            <div id="inner_cont_2">
                <p class="stair_image_font_style">Single Winder<br/>Staircase</p>

                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/fc0" alt="straight staircase">
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
      <div class="row text_center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
            <div id="inner_cont_3">
                <p class="stair_image_font_style">Double Winder<br/>Staircase</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/fc0" alt="straight staircase">
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
      <div class="row text_center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
            <div id="inner_cont_4">
                <p class="stair_image_font_style">Triple Winder<br/>Staircase</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/fc0" alt="straight staircase">
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. I also removed your `.staircase_imgs` class as it's not required once you remove the `.row` elements. I also rearranged some of your markup like `a` to inside the Bootstrap column element. This way the white space around the column element isn't clickable.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. I thought that a row always had to be defined after the col class. Am I wrong for thinking this? I'm new to bootstrap

Comment: @Reece you should only define a new `row` when you've filled up the full-width of the page with 12 columns. Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pc82tnue/2/) for a simple explenation

Comment: @Reece it's always `.row` and then column class elements. If you ever wanted to negate the padding for a particular element you could do what you have done. Just review the [**docs for the grid system**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and all will be well. Also, I'd suggest you ignore Deathstorm's comment, it's either incorrect or incomplete. While the usage would be atypical you _**don't** have to_ fill a row with 12 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `<div class="row">` you have. This creates `margin: 0 -15px;` for `.col` to rest in, but you do not have a `-col` in this `.row` ... so simply remove it.

Like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
                <div class="row text_center">
                    <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="inner_cont_3">
                                <div class="row"> <!-- REMOVE THIS DIV -->
                                    <p class="stair_image_font_style">Double Winder<br/>Staircase</p>

                                    <img class="img-responsive staircase_imgs" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/double_winder.jpg" alt="straight staircase">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should place your `a` tag inside bootstrap column, in order to be inside that padding column. Second, you added unnecessary `.row` classes.
Your structure should be something like this:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col_divide">
            <div class="row text_center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="inner_cont_1">
                             <a href="#" class="image_link_styling">
                                <p class="stair_image_font_style">Straight<br/>Staircase</p>

                                <img class="img-responsive staircase_imgs" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/straight.jpg" alt="straight staircase">

                                 </a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I made a fiddle with your code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teutakoraqi/20djy22f/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

your `<a>` tag starts way outside of the `<img>` tag. Instead of using the `link` over the multiple `<div>`'s try placing the `<a>` tag just around the `<img>` See the example below:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <a href="..">
    <img src="..." class="img-responsive">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the whole box to be clickable but not the padding which is used to divide the columns

Comment: I see, Then it would be the double `<div class="row">` that's creating the issue. You should never nest row's into eachother unless you really want extra whitespaces. @Reece